# Node BehaviorSubject Problem only get empty object

Tags: node.js, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I am using Angular version 7 and trying to use a `BehaviorSubject`
but when I get the value, all times I receive an empty object

[value empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU3LA.png)

```
line: 315 | let value: any = await this._service.machine$.pipe(take(1)).toPromise()
```

Emmit

```
this._service.emitterMachineSelected('new')
```

[code of service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc1qW.png)

Comment: I'd try to run your code to understand what's happening, but my javascript engine doesn't run `.png` files. :P More seriously, your behaviour subject contains an empty object `{ }` so that's what it emits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### _machine's default value

_machine is a `BehaviorSubject` that (to start with) contains an empty object. (`{}` is an empty object). That's how you read the following line:

```ts
_machine = new BehaviorSubject({});
```

So when you grab that value, an empty object (The default value of the `BehaviorSubject`) is what you get.

---

#### Using `.next` to emit a value

Some time later, it contains the string `"new"`

```ts
this_machine.next("new");
```

You're not grabbing this value anywhere, so you shouldn't expect to see it anywhere.

Comment: I understand what is happen, when I send the value. the Subscribe not Exist... What I can do ?